# Any good interview Questions to ask a sybase dba

Tags: sybase

I am a java developer and i will be interviewing sybase dbas along with my boss.
I know some basic stuff about sybase.
Iam looking for good interview questions that i can ask for a sybase dba.
they will be having a min of 4 years of experience. 
I am looking for them to have really good knowledge in performance and tuning related areas like how to measure database performance and suggest ways to improve database design or sybase configuration etc.

Interview is through telephone.

Help much appreciated.

BR

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a question, really, but I would set up a (possibly virtual) machine with a large-ish Sybase database on it and then set about screwing it up as badly as I could, and then sit the DBA candidate down in front of it and see what they can do with it.

I plan to do this for my next set of C# candidates, since I place a great deal of value on debugging ability  and I can't think of any better way than testing it directly.  As a programmer, I would love to do this if I were being interviewed myself.  It's sure to weed out at least the people who know less than you do.

Comment: sounds wickedly cool ;), sadly we do not have such provision to use computers

Answer (score 1):

[This is Microsoft focused but you should be able to glean something from it.](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/iq.htm)